# XML display nods from certain category PHP

Tags: php, xml, file

I have a xml file that looks like that one:

```
<response>

<books>
<link>http:/www.website.com/linktobook/1.html</link>
<title>Book Title 1</title>
<image>http:/www.website.com/linktobook/1.jpg</image>
<category>b</category>
</books>

<books>
<link>http:/www.website.com/musicdvd/2.html</link>
<title>Music DVD 1</title>
<image>http:/www.website.com/musicdvd/2.jpg</image>
<category>m</category>
</books>

<books>
<link>http:/www.website.com/linktobook/3.html</link>
<title>Book Title 3</title>
<image>http:/www.website.com/linktobook/3.jpg</image>
<category>b</category>
</books>

</response>
```

What I want do to is to generate files in for loop (this is working) but only for nodes from certain category (in this example category "b" as books).

This is my PHP script:

```
<?php
$html = "";
$url = "http://website.com/feed.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    ${"file$i"} = "file$i.php";
    $cat = $xml->books[$i]->category;
        if ($cat == "b") {
        $link = $xml->books[$i]->link;
        $title = $xml->books[$i]->title;
        $html .= "<a href=\"$link\">$title</a>";
        file_put_contents(${"file$i"}, $html);
        } else { 
        $i--;
        }
    }
?>
```

Now file0.php is OK and looks like this:

```
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/1.html">Book Title 1</a>
```

But file1.php have 2 nodes insiad and looks like this:

```
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/1.html">Book Title 1</a>
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/2.html">Book Title 2</a>
```

file2.php looks like this:

```
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/1.html">Book Title 1</a>
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/2.html">Book Title 2</a>
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/3.html">Book Title 3</a>
```

And so on. But I want to have only one node in every file.

This is how it should looks like:

file0.php :

```
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/0.html">Book Title 0</a>
```

file1.php :

```
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/1.html">Book Title 1</a>
```

file2.php :

```
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/2.html">Book Title 2</a>
```

And so on to file9.php :

```
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/9.html">Book Title 9</a>
```

Comment: can you please provide output file content you need for above xml?

Comment: all the book links with category 'a' should goto one output file, all the book links with category 'b' should goto one output file, etc.. is that you want?

Comment: I have added how it should looks like.

Comment: I just want to generate files for category "b" and DO NOT generate any file for other categories. So if the script check category of first node and find "b" will generate file. In another node category will be for example "k" and script will not generate file. But it must generate 10 files for category "b".

Comment: ie.. if category is "b" then you need one file with link right?

Comment: yes, if it is other category script must skip and check another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = "http://website.com/feed.xml";
$num=0;
if ($xml = simplexml_load_file($url)) {
    echo $xml->count();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $xml->count(); $i++) {
        $html = "";
        ${"file$num"} = "file$num.php";
        $cat = $xml->books[$i]->category;
        if ($cat == "b") {
            $link = $xml->books[$i]->link;
            $title = $xml->books[$i]->title;
            $html .= "<a href=\"$link\">$title</a>";
            file_put_contents(${"file$num"}, $html);
            $num++;
        }        
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is working. It generate files for all nodes in "b" category. But it is OK. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one item in each file, remove concatenation here:  `$html .= "<a href=\"$link\">$title</a>";`

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to fetch specific nodes from a DOM document.

### DOM

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/response/books[category = "b"]') as $index => $node) {
  echo $index, "\n-----------\n";
  printf(
    '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
    htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(link)', $node)),
    htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $node))
  );
  echo "\n\n";
}
```

### SimpleXML:

```
$response = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($response->xpath('books[category = "b"]') as $index => $books) {
  echo $index, "\n-----------\n";
  printf(
    '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
    htmlspecialchars($books->link),
    htmlspecialchars($books->title)
  );
  echo "\n\n";
}
```

### Output:

```
0
-----------
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/1.html">Book Title 1</a>

1
-----------
<a href="http:/www.website.com/linktobook/3.html">Book Title 3</a>
```

## WARNING!

Don't forget to escape the data you put into HTML. You're generating PHP files. That means source code that will be executed by the browser. Unescaped you allow the injection of PHP source from the data files. You need to be really careful if you're writing PHP files. If possible, write HTML/XML files and use `readfile()` (not `include()`). This way PHP handles the dynamic files as text and you only have to care about the browser.